# QFile / QTextStream don't show error on delete file being written to

Tags: c++, file, qfile, qtextstream

I am writing to a QFile using a QTextStream, and all works great.  I'm trying to create some error detection, so I tried deleting the output file between writes.

Strangle, Qtextstream's status continues to show 0 (no error), and QFile's error method returns 0.  yet the file is gone, and text written is being lost...gone

What's going on?  How can I detect the failure to write?  Am I looking at the wrong methods?

Comment: Show atleast the portion of code which deletes and writes back.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Windows, but on Linux and most Unix-type systems, the scenario you describe is simply not an error at all from the OS's point of view - it's perfectly legal to continue writing to a file that has been deleted (and it "works", data is still shuffled to/from the filesystem - this file is still there in the filesystem until the last handle to it is closed).

(I believe that on Windows you'll get an error if you try to delete the file while it's in use, at least if it was open with the default open mode - not 100% sure though.)

If you need to check for "file deleted", you'll need to write those checks yourself.

Comment: How would I check for file deleted? (this is under Linux).  Is there a function associated with the Qfile that tells me THIS file is still present (not just one with the same name)?  My fear is that since this is a log file, there is a chance logrotate (or something similar) will create an identically named file...so I need to check THIS file...

Comment: This is actually relatively hard to do properly. One method would be to use `handle()` to get the underlying C file descriptor, and `fstat` that. If `st_nlink` is zero, the file is deleted (not visible in the fs hierarchy). If non-zero (file could have been moved), compare `st_dev` and `st_ino` with a `stat()` of the filename. If they don't match, the file has been "rotated". I believe logrotate can be set to send a signal to apps when it does its job. That's probably the sanest approach to this issue.

Comment: Oh, and the other obvious way for not having to worry about that is to reopen the file whenever you need to log. Unless you've got a very high log rate, that's most likely the best solution, @Michelle.